# Are these adjectives fitting?

Tags: adjectives

The motel was located by a **lonely** road cutting through **deserted** landscape.

I think you get the picture. Are the adjectives fitting? Please share if you have some better ones. Thank you.

Comment: Are they fitting for what? What’s the full scenario you’re trying to set out? We can’t tell you whether they’re correct or not without an idea of what you’re trying to communicate.

Comment: The motel and road are in the middle of nowhere and there are no cars on the road.

Comment: The adjectives are right. I would probably write this sentence, "The motel was on a lonely road cutting through a deserted landscape." The word "located" is superfluous and you don't need it. An article (either "a" or "the") sounds better to me with "deserted landscape."

Comment: This forum is not intended to give advice on creative writing!